# django.urls.reverse(): URL-encoding the slash

Tags: python, django

When one supplies URL args or kwargs to a `django.urls.reverse()` call,
Django will nicely URL-encode non-Ascii characters and URL-reserved characters.
For instance, given a declaration such as

```
path("prefix/<stuff>", view=MyView.as_view(), name="myurl")
```

we get

```
reverse('myurl', args=['aaa bbb']) == "/prefix/aaa%20bbb"
reverse('myurl', args=['aaa%bbb']) == "/prefix/aaa%25bbb"
reverse('myurl', args=['Ä']) == "/prefix/%C3%84"
```

and so on. So far, so good.
What Django will *not* encode, however, is the slash:

```
reverse('myurl', args=['aaa/bbb'])
```

will give us

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 
Reverse for 'myurl' with arguments '('aaa/bbb',)' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['prefix/(?P<stuff>[^/]+)$']
```

(The question what to encode and what not
[has been discussed as a Django issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22223).
It's complicated.)

I found a remark in the code that may explain why
the slash is a special case:
`_reverse_with_prefix` in `django/urls/resolvers.py` contains a comment that says

```
 # WSGI provides decoded URLs, without %xx escapes, and the URL
 # resolver operates on such URLs. First substitute arguments
 # without quoting to build a decoded URL and look for a match.
 # Then, if we have a match, redo the substitution with quoted
 # arguments in order to return a properly encoded URL.
```

Given that unencoded arguments are used in the matching initially,
it is no wonder that it does not work:
The slash looks like the end of the argument to Django and so there is
one more argument than expected.

My question:
I dearly want to use user-supplied data in natural-looking URLs,
so **slashes occur occasionally. How can I make them work?**

The URL structure I need is basically

```
/show_rooms/<organization>/<department>/<building>
```

I can think of these approaches:

1. Replace a slash in an argument with some exotic Unicode character
   that will never occur otherwise. And back for received arguments.
   This would sort of do the job, but is inconvenient,
   non-standard, and therefore ugly.
2. Use slugs instead of the real names.
   This would require extending my models to store the slugs (because
   the ORM needs to find objects by them) and appears out of proportion to me.
3. URL-quote my arguments before passing them to `reverse()`
   and unquote arguments when I receive them.
   This is as inconvenient as (1).
   It leads to URLs that are more difficult to read than
   those from (1), because each `%` produced by quoting
   will subsequently be encoded as `%25`.
   But at least it is a standard-ish approach.
   Sigh. Is this really the "right" way?

**Any comments or fourth solutions are welcome!**

Now that I've written it up, solution (1) does not look quite
so horrible to me. **What replacement character would you use for a slash?**

Comment: I would say that the reason `/` are not encoded is not because of the reason you give but because they can actually be part of the argument since the `path` converter or urlpatterns that use regex (`re_path` or the old `url`) can easily accept `/` in the capture parameters

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to pass the slash in as a regular URL and see if your view is able to match with it. If that's the case and the problem is in the `reverse` function itself not the view. How about passing the slash already encoded `%2F`?

Comment: `%2F` is not a suitable only replacement because it could in principle be a valid part of a, say, building name. If that happens, I would replace it by slash and the DB search would fail.

Comment: If you want to achieve this structure `/show_rooms/<organization>/<department>/<building>`

why not write the router as follows
`path("/show_rooms/<int:organization_id>/<int:department_id>/<int:building_id>", view=MyView.as_view(), name="myurl")`

Answer (score 0):

It's me, the asker.

Here is the solution that I finally used:
I decided for solution (1).
It turned out less inconvenient than I had expected and
it works spectacularly well.
My Firefox browser shows the URL in text form, not urlencoded form,
and when you pick the right replacement character it looks almost natural.
Very nice.

Here is the code for the escaping (to be called in the template, hence a
[custom templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/))
and unescaping (to be called in the view):

```
import django.template as djt

register = djt.Library()
# see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/

ALT_SLASH = '\N{DIVISION SLASH}'


@register.filter
def escape_slash(urlparam: str) -> str:
    """
    Avoid having a slash in the urlparam URL part, 
    because it would not get URL-encoded.
    See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67849991/django-urls-reverse-url-encoding-the-slash
    Possible replacement characters are
    codepoint   char    utf8    name    oldname
    U+2044  ⁄   e2 81 84    FRACTION SLASH
    U+2215  ∕   e2 88 95    DIVISION SLASH
    U+FF0F  ／   ef bc 8f    FULLWIDTH SOLIDUS   FULLWIDTH SLASH
    None of them will look quite right if the browser shows the char rather than
    the %-escape in the address line, but DIVISION SLASH comes close.
    The normal slash is
    U+002F  /   2f  SOLIDUS     SLASH
    To get back the urlparam after calling escape_slash, 
    the URL will be formed (via {% url ... } or reverse()) and URL-encoded, 
    sent to the browser,
    received by Django in a request, URL-unencoded, split, 
    its param parts handed to a view as args or kwargs,
    and finally unescape_slash will be called by the view.
    """
    return urlparam.replace('/', ALT_SLASH)


def unescape_slash(urlparam_q: str) -> str:
    return urlparam_q.replace(ALT_SLASH, '/')
```